# How to get opened websites in browser with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, browser

I want to see all the websites that are opened in the currently working browser.
Let's say that person is currently watching something on www.youtube.com and I want to see with that script that www.youtube.com is opened.

Code:

```
# something like this
import someModule
openedURLs = someModule.openedulrs()
```

I know this code is useless but it is just some example how I would use it.

Is this even possible? If yes with what modules?

Thanks!

Comment: This won't work. You'll also get a lot of trouble with data protection regulations if you want to use such scripts outside of your own machine.

Comment: While it is likely *technically* possible to do what you are asking (ie. using computer vision or perhaps some custom browser API), it isn't very *feasible*, and is generally a Bad Idea™.

Do you have a specific use case you could mention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is impossible (hopefully).

Python can only access what browsers are exposing through their API. I am currently not aware of any browsers offering an API for external applications to query the list of currently opened websites' urls. If they did, that would be a huge security issue. Those functions only exist in internal APIs for the browser extensions.